# About using the estimated prices function

Tags: uber-api

Hi this is my first post and I have a question. 
Currently we are having a thesis app development. We are gonna make a carpool app price finder that compares 2 carpool app. But I dont know how its gonna work, we thought that we can use the estimate price in the Uber API (just that) or if just have a formula or algorithm on how they estimate your prices. We are struggling currently in our thesis.

Answer (score 0):

**Please ensure that your use of Uber API endpoints complies with the [API Terms of Use](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/terms-of-use)**. Using the Uber API to offer price comparisons with competitive third party services is in violation of [§ II B](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/terms-of-use#section-b-use-restrictions) of the API Terms of Use. Please make sure that you familiarize yourself with the API Terms of Use to avoid losing access to this service.